# Comparing significant differences between a linear regression on same data coded as ordinal or interval

Tags: regression, statistical-significance, multiple-regression, ordinal-data

I'm running linear regressions in R on some survey data that was delivered as Likert-scales. In R, I can code them as factors (to represent them as ordinal data) or numeric (to represent them as interval data), and from there R will automatically apply different contrasts to make them fit in a linear regression. The whole process is a bit of a black box for me but what I found is that the models created in either case appear to be similar.

The same predictors in either case are significant. Different metrics commonly used to evaluate the explanatory power like R^2 and RMSE are also similar - of course "similar" is a vague term based on my own eye-test. I was advised that if the models in either case looked similar enough, I could proceed treating the data as interval for simplicity's sake.

1. Is this an appropriate way to decide how to code my predictors?
2. Is there an objective to compare the similarity between the two models and say that there's no significant difference?

Answer (score 0):

Linearity is nearly always wrong in regression; your case is no exception.  The effect on $Y$ of an increase from $X=1$ to $X=2$ is almost certainly different from the effect of an increase from $X=4$ to $X=5$.

However, we use linear models not because they are right, but instead because (a) they are easier to use and interpret, and (b) they can can provide better predictions, even when wrong.

As regards (b), you might consider out-of-sample (like $n$-fold cross-validation) prediction accuracy for the models.  If linearity is not too badly violated, then the added variance from estimating so many more parameters in your factor model may be worse than the bias caused by nonlinearity, resulting in a lower cross-validated error estimate for the linear model.

Another approach you might consider is this:

(1) Consider a particular predictor of interest, say $X_1$.

(2) Construct a frequency table of that variable so you know how many observations are at $X_1=1$, $X_1=2$, ..., $X_1=5$.

(3) Fit both models, the linear and the factor.

(4) Setting all other $X$ variables at either means or modes, find the predicted values of $Y$ for $X_1=1$, $X_1=2$, ..., $X_1=5$, using each model.

(5) Graph both functions (predicted $Y$ as a function of $X_1$) on the same set of axes and compare.

The deviation of the factor-based function from the linear function will give you an idea of how much of a problem there is with nonlinearity. The frequency tables you constructed in step (2) will help you to interpret the deviations in light of the sample sizes. (Larger deviations are expected by chance alone when sample sizes are smaller.)